# How to perform a conditional calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Trying to deal with an issue how to implement dictionary to existing DataFrame's column by certain indexes, i.e.:

Primary DataFrame:

```
             country    year      Corruption Index
0            X          2010           6,5
1            X          2015          78,0
```

So I have dictionary (separately devide 78 by 10):

```
x = {1: 7,8}
```

I want to change value of index **1**, column **'Corruption Index'**.
I now I can use *for loop*, but are there any faster variants ? Or maybe I can directly divide values in Existing DataFrame which values are higher than 10 by ten? (the problem is that official statistics after 2012 turns from 1-10 to 1-100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The fastest solution is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65443409/7758804) from [Mykola Zotko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8973620/mykola-zotko)
- For a vectorized solution, use [`pandas.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), which will *replace values where the condition is `False`*.

  - `.where` will be much faster than using [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), as `df['Corruption Index'].apply(lambda x: x/10 if x > 10 else x)`
- [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is slightly different, in that it works on the `True` condition, and is faster than `pandas.DataFrame.where`, but requires importing `numpy`.
- Since this issue seems to be related to *official statistics after 2012 turns from 1-10 to 1-100*, `m = df.year <= 2012` should be used as the condition.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['X', 'X'], 'year': [2010, 2015], 'Corruption_Index': [6.5, 78.0]})

# display(df)
  country  year  Corruption_Index
0       X  2010               6.5
1       X  2015              78.0

# create a Boolean mask for the condition
m = df.year <= 2012

# use pandas.DataFrame.where to calculate on the False condition
df['Corruption_Index'].where(m, df['Corruption_Index'] / 10, inplace=True)

# alternatively, use np.where to calculate on the True condition
df['Corruption_Index'] = np.where(df.year > 2012, df['Corruption_Index'] / 10, df['Corruption_Index'])

# display(df)
  country  year  Corruption_Index
0       X  2010               6.5
1       X  2015               7.8
```

### `%%timeit` Comparison

```py
# test data with 1M rows
np.random.seed(365)
df = pd.DataFrame({'v': [np.random.randint(20) for _ in range(1000000)]})

%%timeit
df.loc[df['v'] > 10, 'v'] /= 10
[out]:
2.66 ms ± 61.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
np.where(df['v'] > 10, df['v'] / 10, df['v'])
[out]:
8.11 ms ± 403 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
df['v'].where(df['v'] <= 10, df['v'] / 10)
[out]:
17.9 ms ± 615 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
df['v'].apply(lambda x: x/10 if x > 10 else x)
[out]:
319 ms ± 29.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df.loc[df['Corruption_Index'] > 10, 'Corruption_Index'] /= 10
```